# Neo4j Graph DB - London Subway Planner - Path not found

Tags: graph, path, neo4j

I have created a map of the London Underground in Neo4j. Stations are connected via :CONNECTED_TO relationships with a time value denoting how long it takes between stops (at the moment these are random values I put in for testing). Stations which are on multiple lines have a node for each line, connected by a :PART_OF relationship. Using this query:

```
MATCH (from {name:"Wood Green"}), (to {name:"Royal Oak"}), 
p = shortestPath((from)-[*]-(to))
WITH REDUCE(time = 0, rel in rels(p) | time + rel.time) AS time, p
RETURN p, time
ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1
```

I am able to get the shortest path below:
 [image: Shortest route from Wood Green to Royal Oak]

This route is on 4 different lines, and manages to find the route with no problem.

If I change the query to go from Royal Oak to Bounds Green (the next station on the Piccadilly line from Wood Green) I get no results found. The node 'Bounds Green' node exists as does the relationship between Wood Green and Bounds Green.

I can't imagine this is a limit on the number of nodes in the chain. But I haven't got much experience in uing Neo4j and I'm a bit stuck.

Any insights greatly appreciated, thanks.

-ifor

Comment: Pretty. Can you please provide the changed query and also your database (which shouldn't be that large). There was a limit of 15 in the chain, but you  can increase it by using `(a)-[*..30]->(b)`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Michael. I assumed `[*]` would give an infinite chain. Changing to `[*..30]` solved the issues. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael mentioned, there seems to be a limit of 15 relationships between nodes when running a `(a)-[*]-(b)` query. Changing the query to use `(a)-[*..30]-(b)` solved the issue.

```
MATCH (from {name: "STATION_NAME_A" }), (to {name: "STATION_NAME_B" }), 
p = shortestPath((from)-[*..30]-(to))
WITH REDUCE(time = 0, rel in rels(p) | time + rel.time) AS time, p
RETURN p, time
ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1
```